# Sci-fi book series about two orphan boys who are adopted and trained by two monster hunters

Tags: story-identification

So a while ago I started a sci-fi book series that I want to either re-read or check to see if there are more books that have been released since.

The story revolves around two orphan boys who are adopted by two monster hunters who are really rich and at least one of them is nobility. One mentor is a brute named Asher who trains the bigger orphan boy. Of the two orphan boys one is more of a main character - in fact, his name has something to do with the names of the books.

The other orphan boy ends up being a half-giant and going to live with the giants for a bit and then later a school that has multiple other races, including trolls. The headmistress of the school is also a troll.

The main orphan is extremely intelligent and learns very quickly under the tutelage of one of the monster hunters, who has a military background. The main character's mentor is also part dragon or something along those lines and has some magical ability.

Also the main character was raised by a grandmother figure who was actually part dragon and really old. He was orphaned when she was killed by a 'red mage'. Red mages are the main antagonists. His 'grandmother' leaves him with a magical trunk with some artifacts inside of it

Edit. Some dragons decided to take human form long before the main story. The mentor not named asher is the one who is part dragon and he is able to turn invisible and is more of a roguish character that pretends not to care about anyone but truly does. I know there is at least 2 books and I read them about two years ago. I'm not sure when they were published but it is definitely post 2000.

Comment: What are monster hunters? Are they monsters who go hunting, or are they hunters who hunt monsters?

Answer (score 4):

The series is *Heritage of the Blood* and the first book is *[Victor Deus](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22737546-victor-deus)*. Great series except its editing needs work.

> Every culture has it's legends. Those men and women who's legacies were so great that their stories have been repeated generation to generation. A person of such impact that other cultures long detached from the origins tell stories of these powerful individuals. Such is the story of Victor Deus. Unlike many such legends, there was little need to embellish the deeds he and his allies accomplished. Some remember him as a savior, some as a tyrant. There are whole worlds that worship him like a god, and others that raise him up as a devil. All of these worlds agree upon one thing though, he was fiercely protective of his allies, and swiftly dealt with his enemies.
>
> How does one become such a figure? Loved by so many, yet feared by even more? The story is a long one, and I hope you will bear with me as the story unfolds. One thing you must know about Victor Deus is that he was not given time to be a child, for his formative years were full of training and despair. Therefor, it is there where this story begins, a boy, barely able to hold a sword, thrust into events he cannot control.

Comment: Excellent. Can you provide any further details in your answer as to how it fits, like quoting a summary? And you can accept your own answer in about 46 hours by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Even though you're the OP and can confirm this, it would be helpful to others who may be having the same problem so that they can confirm if it's what *they're* looking for as well. Check out [How to write a good story-ID answer?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9444/21267) for tips on what points to include.